How to install a Word Addin that I developed for myself
I developed a Word AddIn using the Yeoman Generator in vs Code. How can I use the AddIn in my word instance without having to sideload it from vs Code? I don't have the option to upload/install it in the "my Addins" section. I don't need to publish it to anyone else.
I have tried uploading/installing it in Word. I also tried to somehow use a network storage and Azure storage instance. This failed but I just want to use it locally anyway.
